# Angular RouterLink Parameters - Activated Route not working

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

I am trying to get routerLink Parameter using ActivatedRoute.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.pageTitle = this.route.snapshot.params['title'];
}
```

It shows the parameter first time only. But not again when the parameter is changed.

Link to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-example-nb5jhq?file=app%2Fsearch-page%2Fsearch-page.component.ts) example.

When I click **Search Page a** it shows title is *test*. But when I click on **Search Page b** it still keeps on showing title is *test* even though the title is *testing*. However when I click **Home** and then **Search Page b** it shows the updated parameter as *testing*.

How do I fix the issue so that when click **Search Page b** after **Search Page a** it shows me the updated parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it, it works one time and one time only. It won't work for your criteria. If you would like to react, you have to do it in an observable way.

Try:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.pageTitle = params['title'];
      });
```

Everytime the params changes, you will get a notification and the subscription will kick in and change the `pageTitle`.